# Is a value stored in registers/memory an address or the contents?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I cannot understand this. My concept just went from 50% to 0.
What does `mov eax, 23h` do? Does it store the value 23h to `eax` register or the address 23h (in `eax`)? Should it not be storing the value of 23 hexadecimal in `eax`?

if *.data* contains

```
value Word 230
```

and our instructions contain

```
mov ax, value
```

What will this do? Store 230 in `ax` or get the address of value and store it in `ax`?
Lastly what if we write this code

```
mov ax, [value]
```

Comment: which assembler? In MASM/TASM `mov ax,value` is compiled as `mov ax,[<memory_address_into_data>]`, in NASM it will compile as `mov ax,<memory_address_into_data>`, i.e. ax = number. (as address is number too, there's no difference between `23h` value and `23h` address). `mov ax,[value]` is in all common assemblers what it says, it will fetch value `230` from memory and store it into `ax` (if `ds` is pointing to data segment).

Comment: MASM procedures please!

Comment: The MASM syntax is inconsistent, the memory fetching is written differently depending whether you have address in register (`mov eax,[ebx]`) or whether you use symbolic address (`mov eax,value`). You can still write even in MASM `mov eax,[value]` to make it easier to read for people like me, who love to have all memory accesses visibly marked by square brackets in source, as those brackets will get ignored. To load the address itself of symbol `value` in MASM you have to use `OFFSET` keyword, like: `mov eax, OFFSET value`, that's different from NASM, which requires `[]` around memory access.

Comment: Also MASM is trying hard to keep track of "type" of particular symbol, i.e. `inc value` will compile as `inc word ptr [value]` when `value` was defined as `value dw 1`, and it will compile as `inc byte ptr [value]` when you used `value db 1, 0` to define it, but I strongly discourage for exploiting this behaviour of MASM, usually when you need to write some piece of ASM, you need it because you want to talk directly in machine language, not in some highlevel chit-chat of types and stuff, so these automagical deductions from compiler instead of reporting error with ambiguity are annoying to me.

Comment: I rather prefer source which is precise and explicit, like `inc word ptr [value]`, stating explicitly the intent of programmer to modify whole `word` of memory content (no matter how the `value` symbol was defined).

Comment: Thank you. I understand things now. Way better.